# Parallel.ForEach with tuple return c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach, parallel-processing

Based on this [example](http://reedcopsey.com/2010/01/22/parallelism-in-net-part-4-imperative-data-parallelism-aggregation/) I'm trying to make a parallel foreach with tuple return.

```
double min = double.MaxValue;

object syncObject = new object(); 
Parallel.ForEach(collection, () => double.MaxValue, (item, loopState, 
    localState) =>
    {
        double value = item.PerformComputation();
        return System.Math.Min(localState, value);
    },
    localState =>
    {
        lock(syncObj)
            min = System.Math.Min(min, localState);
    }
);

Console.Write(min + "\n");
```

The above code works fine but in my occasion(correct minimum value) but i don't want to output the minimum value but the 'name' of that value so i tried something like this:

```
double min = double.MaxValue;
string minName = "";

object syncObject = new object(); 
Parallel.ForEach(collection, () => Tuple.Create(double.MaxValue, ""), (item, 
    loopState, localState) =>
    {
        double value = PerformComputation(item.Item1.Value);
        string name = item.Item1.Key;

        return //helpHere
    },
    localState =>
    {
        lock(syncObj)
            min = //help here
            minName = //help here
    }
);

Console.Write(minName + "\n");
```

Tried couple things that didn't work. Also I've read [microsoft's example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-foreach-loop-with-thread-local-variables) without luck. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not very much context in your question. It would have been better for you to provide a good [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that showed exactly what you're doing. But, it *appears* as though in your second version of the code, you have changed the computational model from an object with a `PerformComputation()` method, to a `PerformComputation()` method that is locally defined, and a collection of some kind of `Tuple` object, where the `Item1` member is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` of some sort.

Making those assumptions, something like this should work in your scenario:

```
Tuple<double, string> result = Tuple.Create(double.MaxValue, "");

object syncObject = new object(); 
Parallel.ForEach(collection, () => Tuple.Create(double.MaxValue, ""),
    (item, loopState, localState) =>
    {
        double value = PerformComputation(item.Item1.Value);

        if (value < localState.Item1)
        {
            localState = Tuple.Create(value, item.Item1.Key);
        }

        return localState;
    },

    localState =>
    {
        lock(syncObj)
        {
            if (localState.Item1 < result.Item1)
            {
                result = localState;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped me and I solved my problem. Sorry for not providing my code example correctly, net time i'll know.

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure I understand the example, but should be easier with PLINQ:

```
string minName = collection.AsParallel()
     .Min(item => Tuple.Create(PerformComputation(item.Item1.Value), item.Item1.Key)).Item2;
```